# TinyMce picture tag wrapper

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

In out CMS we put every image inside "picture" tag like this:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp"> <img class="_img_resp" 
     src="image.jpe" alt="Image"> 
</picture>
```

But tiny wraps every picture tag inside "p"
I see that some tags like: "ul", "div", "h2" are wrappers itself without additional "p"
So, can i made "picture" tag a new custom wrapper?
I dont need deleting root "p" tag from all content

I use tinymcy 5.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved it with this

```
custom_elements: 'picture',
valid_children: 'picture[source|img]',
formats: {
   'custom_picture': {block: 'picture', selector: 'picture', merge_siblings: true, wrapper: true},
         }
```

Not clear, but it works